# 2 textViews in a view controller, but the view controller is not scrolling?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have 2 textViews in a viewController the 2nd textview is larger then screen, and the ViewController is not scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put these views in a UIScrollView for the viewController's content to be scrollable.

Comment: @worriorbg- tried a foo project and implemented 2 textviews on Scrollable viewController..but still it's not scrolling..

Comment: You need to set to contentSize property of the UIScrollView to enclose the total area of the views.